# ERROR: subquery must return only one column - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to query a report and it's returning this and I don't know how to resolve it. Can someone help me?

```
  select
    ` public.produtofornecedor.id_fornecedor,`
   ``  public.fornecedor.nomefantasia`, 
     public.produto.id as item,
    ` `public.produto.descricaocompleta`,`
     `public.produtoautomacao.codigobarras`,
     `public.produtocomplemento.descontinuado`, 
     `(select descricao as status from situacaocadastro where id=1
       and (select id as numero_loja,descricao from loja where id <> 2))`

from public.produto
join public.produtofornecedor on public.produto.id =                public.produtofornecedor.id_produto
join public.produtoautomacao on public.produto.id = public.produtoautomacao.id_produto
join public.fornecedor on public.fornecedor.id = public.produtofornecedor.id_fornecedor
join public.produtocomplemento on public.produtocomplemento.id_produto = public.produtoautomacao.id_produto
       -- where cast(public.produtoautomacao.codigobarras as varchar) not like '1230%'
   --and CHAR_LENGTH(cast(public.produtoautomacao.codigobarras as varchar)) > 7
    where public.produtocomplemento.descontinuado = false
    --and public.produtofornecedor.id_fornecedor = #ID DO FORNECEDOR:2::::0:true:#
         and public.produtofornecedor.id_fornecedor = 611
             order by public.produto.id;
```

Comment: `where id=1 and (select id as numero_loja,descricao from loja where id <> 2)` is no valid syntax. What do you attempt to filter here?

Comment: I'm trying to make the query filter three of the four stores that have a table with the stores, but I don't know the best way to do this.

Comment: because I need the stores to be validated to display the query result, so that it only brings results from three stores and not from all stores.

Comment: I tried that way too, but it's not going, I don't know if it's because I'm inserting more than one subquery.